# requests module returns JSON with items unordered

Tags: node.js

When I'm using node's requests module this way:

```
router.get('http://[some_api_url]')
res.send()
```

I get different JSON ordered in contrary to viewing the JSON via browser.

For example, via `res.send()` I get:

```
[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]
```

Whereas via browser I see it as supposed to be:

```
[{"key2":"value2","key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2","key1":"value1"}],
```

The function is this:

```
getAllEvnets:async(req, res)=> {
    let event = []
    try{
        var listEvent = await events.findAll()
        for (let i = 0; i < listEvent.length; i++) {
        event.push({
        id: listEvent[i].id_event,
        start: listEvent[i].debut,
        end : listEvent[i].fin,
        title: listEvent[i].title,
        color: {red: {
        primary: '#ad2121',
       secondary: '#FAE3E3'}
  },
      actions: ''
  })
       }
res.json(event)
        }
    catch(err){
        res.send(err.message)
        }
}
```

Comment: Objects aren't ordered, why does that matter?

Answer (score 1):

ECMAscript says...

> The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties ... is not
>   specified.

So there is no guarantee that it will be ordered. Anyway usually it dont need it to be ordered you acces it with an dot notation like `key1.value1`. No matter if its the first property in the object or the last one, it doenst matter.

Comment: in angular6 I need it oedered , in postman it returns like that ```{
        "id": 3,
        "start": "",
        "end": "",
        "title": "tt2",
        "color": {
            "red": {
                "primary": "#ad2121",
                "secondary": "#FAE3E3"
            }
        },
        "actions": ""
    },```
but in browser it becomes ordered alphabetically